# How to remove empty element from numpy array

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, slice

Here an example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3,4], [], [1,2,0,9]]) 

print(a)
# array([list([1, 2, 3, 4]), list([]), list([1, 2, 0, 9])], dtype=object)
```

How to remove the empty element and return only:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 0, 9]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use logical indexing:

```
a[a.astype(bool)]
# array([list([1, 2, 3, 4]), list([1, 2, 0, 9])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the array:-

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3,4], [], [1,2,0,9]]) 
a1 = np.array([i for i in a if i])

>>> a1
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 0, 9]])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use filter:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3,4], [], [1,2,0,9]]) 
list(filter(None, a))

# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 0, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop iteration over array and computing length will be enough to get rid of empty elements.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[],[5,6,7,8]]
output = []
for elem in a:
    if elem:
          output.append(elem)
output= np.array(output)
```

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `output`?  Compared to the original `a `?

Comment: Output would be a numpy array, of shape: (numpy.ndarray, (2, 4))